# In Matching function, post back the row of a matched element

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to recreate some of my `vba` macros as functions as `Google App Scripts`

No doubt there are different ways to do this but this is helping me translate my `vba` skills into `gas`

I want to post back all the `row cells` when a match is found

The MatchColumns function works well when I post back `only` the matched cell but I can not get how to post back the row of the matched cell

I get the error `Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 72`

//Look in sheet name

//Look with sheet Name

//Post back sheet name

//The Look in column header for matching

//The Look with column header for matching

```
function MatchColumns(sShtName,tShtName,pbShtName,matchIn, matchWith){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var LookInSht = ss.getSheetByName(sShtName);
  var LookWithSht = ss.getSheetByName(tShtName);
  var PBSheet = ss.getSheetByName(pbShtName);

  var LookIn = LookInSht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var LookWith = LookWithSht.getDataRange().getValues();

  var matchColIn = CHTCN(sShtName,matchIn);
  var matchColWith = CHTCN(tShtName,matchWith);

  var list = [];
  var listRows = [];

  for (i in LookIn){
    var curName = LookIn[i][matchColIn];
    var exists = true;

    for (j in LookWith){
      var curCheck = LookWith[j][matchColWith];
      if (curCheck == curName){
        listRows = LookIn[i]; //Get the ROW of the match
        exists = false;
        break;
      };
    }; // end for j

    list.push([exists ? "" : curName]);

  } // end for i

  //This is the "return list" post back that works when only returning the match; 
  //PBSheet.getRange(2, PBSheet.getLastColumn() +1, list.length, 1).setValues(list);

  // My new post back tring to return the entire row
  PBSheet.getRange(2, PBSheet.getLastColumn() +1, list.length,     LookInSht.getLastColumn()).setValues([listRows]);
}
```

Column Header To Column Number

```
function CHTCN(ShtName,name){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ShtName).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(name);
  return colindex;
}
```